# Customize the formatting of bibliographic entries

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{\bf Minimal Example}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Here initial concepts and conditions are explained and
several hypothesis are mentioned in brief.

\citep*{allen}, \citep*{bruner} and \citep*{cox}
did the initial work in this area. But in Struss' work \citep{cox}
the definitive model is seen.   

\begin{thebibliography}{9}


    \bibitem[Allen, B.S.~(1985)]{allen}
    {\bf Allen, B.S.} (1984). System-assigned learning strategies and CBI.
    \emph{Journal of Instructional Computing Research},
    \emph{1}(1), 3--18.
    %\filbreak

    \bibitem[Bruner, J.~(1960)]{bruner}
    {\bf Bruner, J.}(1960). \emph{The process of education}.
    New York: Random House.
    %\filbreak

    \bibitem[Cox, S.~R.~(1974)]{cox}
    {\bf Cox, S.~R.}(1974). Computer-assisted instruction and student performance
    in macroeconomic principles.
    \emph{The Journal of Economic Education},
    \emph{6}(1), 29--37.
    %\filbreak

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and its output is

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need to customize the bibliography style like below

[image]

[image]

[image]

How is it possible ?

Comment: Please provide code for a minimal document people can compile and show us what you've got so far. Or try one of the apa-alike BibTeX styles. I don't use BibTeX any longer, but there are lots of styles, include APA like one.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with the way BibTeX `.bst` files are programmed, the usual answer is 'with some difficulty'. But it is impossible to even give good starting advice at this point. Without the minimal file cfr requested, it is unclear how you are generating your bibliography, what it looks like, and what elements need to change. We need at least a minimal `.tex` file and a `.bib` file with those three entries in order to help.

Comment: @cfr :My complete file is uploaded in the link [link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1UK76PqW_WYUWVZRnF3blk0ZWM

Comment: @jon :My complete file is uploaded in the link [link]drive.google.com/open?id=0B1UK76PqW_WYUWVZRnF3blk0ZWM

Comment: Few people, I suspect, and this does include me, are eager to read through a 'complete file'. Both cfr and I asked for a **minimal** document; this is known as a ['minimal working example'](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). (Note that it is 'minimal' in the sense that it contains **only** what is needed to reproduce the problem or effect you are asking about, **not** because it means the person asking the questions will need to put in only a minimal amount of effort to create it.)

Comment: What @jon said ^^. Please read the information linked to in jon's comment.

Comment: @jon : I have added minimal example.Please help me

Comment: @cfr :  I have added minimal example.Please help me

Comment: Is it essential that the numbers that prefix the formatted entries be typeset using a sans-serif font? If so, does it matter *which* sans-serif font is used?

Comment: `\bibliographystyle` etc. isn't really doing anything for you, as you're setting the bibliography by hand. Also, please don't use `\bf`. It is 20+ years obsolete in LaTeX. Try `\bfseries` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're building the bibliography entirely by hand. If this impression is correct, there's nothing to stop you from adding "1.", "2.", and "3." to the material after the citation label, is there?

*Addendum*: The screenshot you posted would appear to suggest that the numbers that prefix the formatted bibliographic entries should be typeset using a sans-serif font. If this is the case, just replace `{\bfseries1. Allen, B.~S.}` with  `{\bfseries\textsf{1.} Allen, B.~S.}`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{\bfseries Minimal Example}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Here initial concepts and conditions are explained and
several hypothesis are mentioned in brief.

\citep*{allen}, \citep*{bruner} and \citep*{cox}
did the initial work in this area. 
But in Struss' work \citep{cox} the definitive model is seen.   

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Allen, B.~S. (1985)]{allen}
    {\bfseries1. Allen, B.~S.} (1984). System-assigned learning strategies and CBI.
    \emph{Journal of Instructional Computing Research},
    \emph{1}(1), 3--18.

\bibitem[Bruner, J. (1960)]{bruner}
    {\bfseries2. Bruner, J.} (1960). \emph{The process of education}.
    New York: Random House.

\bibitem[Cox, S.~R. (1974)]{cox}
    {\bfseries3. Cox, S.~R.} (1974). Computer-assisted instruction and student performance
    in macroeconomic principles.
    \emph{The Journal of Economic Education},
    \emph{6}(1), 29--37.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to do hyperlink this references

Comment: @RenjthVRavi - Please be more specific regarding what you mean by "hyperlink th[ese] references". Are you asking about creating hyperlinks from the citation callouts (in the body of the document) to the formatted bib entries, or are you asking about hyperlinking the formatted bib entries to some document repository on the Internet?

Comment: @RenjthVRavi - If it's a matter of creating hyperlinks from the citation callouts to the formatted bib entries, simply add the following instruction in the preamble: `\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}`. (If you don't like blue, choose another color...)

Comment: I have already used the same, but I couldn't link the citation with bibliography

Comment: @RenjthVRavi - Please post a *new question", ideally with a full MWE (minimum working example), in which you raise these concerns. We need to know exactly what your code does, and what it doesn't do.