# Customizing BibTex

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, natbib

How to do the solution of [Customize the formatting of bibliographic entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345465/customize-the-formatting-of-bibliographic-entries) using BibTex with hyperlink

Comment: What do you mean with "BibTeX with hyperlink"?

Comment: @user124577 : The answer by Stefan Pinnow in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169489/how-to-get-a-custom-citation-type-in-bibtex/169506#169506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the code given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350676/5001), you need to add the following instruction to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref} % choose whichever color you like best
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\citep{allen}; \citet{bruner}; \citep{cox}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Allen, B.~S.(1985)]{allen}
    {\bfseries1. Allen, B.~S.} (1984). System-assigned learning strategies and CBI.
    \emph{Journal of Instructional Computing Research}, \emph{1}(1), 3--18.

\bibitem[Bruner, J.(1960)]{bruner}
    {\bfseries2. Bruner, J.} (1960). \emph{The process of education}.
    New York: Random House.

\bibitem[Cox, S.~R.(1974)]{cox}
    {\bfseries3. Cox, S.~R.} (1974). Computer-assisted instruction and student performance
    in macroeconomic principles.
    \emph{The Journal of Economic Education}, \emph{6}(1), 29--37.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```